# how i should use react hook useState with post axios

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, react-hooks

I try call request post with hooks. Firstly, a call request post using this.setState and it working correctly
but I want to use a hook (useState) instead of setState and it doesn't work

code below working correctly

```
export default class AddShoes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.startValue;
    this.state.show = false;
    this.shoesChange = this.shoesChange.bind(this);
  }

  startValue = {
    brand: "",
    model: "",
    date: "",
    price: "",
    img: "",
  };

  shoesChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  submitShoes = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const shoes = {
      brand: this.state.brand,
      model: this.state.model,
      date: this.state.date,
      price: this.state.price,
      img: this.state.img,
    };

    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api", shoes).then((response) => {
      if (response.data != null) {
        this.setState(this.startValue);
        alert("added")
      } 
    });
  };
```

the second code below doesn't work

```
export default function AddShoes() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    brand: "",
    model: "",
    date: "",
    price: "",
    img: "",
  });
  // const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleSetInputs = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const submitShoes = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api", values)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data != null) {
        setValues(response.data);
        alert("added!");
      }
    });
  };
```

what I should change?

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  How specifically is it failing?  What debugging have you done?

Answer (score 0):

To just change one property from an state-object in React Hooks you have to do this:

```
setValues(prevValues => ({ ...prevValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example that works, you are resetting the state by calling `this.setState(this.startValue)`

In the second example, you are passing the result of the network request inside setValue `setValues(response.data)`

Create `initialValues` outside of `AddShoes` function component.

```
const initialValues = {
    brand: "",
    model: "",
    date: "",
    price: "",
    img: "",
  }
```

Now pass that into `setValues` inside `submitShoes`

```
  const submitShoes = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api", values)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data != null) {
        setValues(initialValues);
        alert("added!");
      }
    });
  };
```